Setting Preprocessor Definitions in a referenced project
I would like to conditionally export symbols to be used in a Google Test project in Visual Studio 2019. I am trying to set a preprocessor definition called UNIT_TESTS, but only when the unit test project builds the referenced source project.
The symbols are exporting properly without the conditional #ifdef UNIT_TESTS in the header file, but the preprocessor definition is not propagated to the source project. Is there a way to do this?
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#ifdef UNIT_TESTS

#ifdef INTERFACE_EXPORTS
#define INTERFACE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define INTERFACE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#pragma comment(lib, "Interface.lib")
#endif

INTERFACE_API void func();

#endif // #ifdef UNIT_TESTS
#endif // #ifndef TEST_H


You would need to rebuild the original library with them exporting ... And one project does not build another project, so I'm not really sure that makes sense.

As a clarification, this is two projects in the same solution. One project I refer to as the source, the other is the unit test project.

You need to mention UNIT_TESTS in preprocessor tab of project settings for one of configurations of the source project, and use this configuration for you unit tests. By default, you have 2 project configurations (Debug and Release), but you can add more.

Generally. having different configurations for the code you test and the code the projects actually use is not the best idea. You will only test that the tests work, not that the "real" code works.

@BoP I would prefer to only expose the API in the library, but unit test the underlying function calls in my project. The API functions will also be tested.

The preprocessor definition will not be propagated between projects. You need to add it in the preprocessor definition setting of the unit test project.
Or define the macro before the header file (precompiled header file is on the first line)
in test.cpp
#include "pch.h"
//
#define UNIT_TESTS
#include"...lib header.h"


I ended up adding the UNIT_TEST definition to only the Debug configuration of the source project. Not my desired implementation since the unit test project must be built in debug configuration for it to work, but it works.
